# kotlin: Generic to different types

Tags: generics, kotlin

I need linear functions like this:

```
class Linear(val a : Double, val b : Double) {
    fun eval(in : Double) {
        return a*in + b
    }
}
```

Then, I need the same thing for vectors.

```
class Vector3d(val a1 : Double, val a2 : Double, val a3 : Double) {
    // use operator overloading https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html to make +, -, /, *, etc. possible for vectors
}

class Linear(val a : Vector3d, val b : Vector3d) {
    fun eval(in : Vector3d) {
        return a*in + b
    }
}
```

As you can see, the two Linear classes are identical (except for argument types). Now, I can not make the class generic, as Double and Vector3d do not have a common superclass.

If I want to write Linear just once, my only option is my own Double-type, which than has a common interface with Vector3d. However, this means I can not use 0 in the source code any longer, but I have to use MyDouble(0) everywhere. I could overload the constructor of Linear to accept Doubles, and create the MyDouble objects internally, however, I would need to do this for every single method in my API.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You do not show how `Vector3d` supports `*` and `+` operations. You definitely need a common parent class/interface or you're stuck with unbound generics.

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce a level of indirection by defining an interface/class that has two implementations/subclasses: one for primitive doubles and one for your `Vector3d`. However you may find the overhead undesirable. e.g.:

```
interface Arithmetical<A : Arithmetical<A>> {
    operator fun plus(other: A): A
    operator fun minus(other: A): A
    operator fun times(other: A): A
    operator fun div(other: A): A
}

class Linear<A : Arithmetical<A>>(val a: A, val b: A) {
    fun eval(`in`: A): A {
        return a * `in` + b
    }
}

class ArithmeticalDouble(val value: Double) : Arithmetical<ArithmeticalDouble> {
    override fun plus(other: ArithmeticalDouble) = ArithmeticalDouble(value + other.value)
    override fun minus(other: ArithmeticalDouble) = ArithmeticalDouble(value - other.value)
    override fun times(other: ArithmeticalDouble) = ArithmeticalDouble(value * other.value)
    override fun div(other: ArithmeticalDouble) = ArithmeticalDouble(value / other.value)
}

class Vector3d(val a1: Double, val a2: Double, val a3: Double) : Arithmetical<Vector3d> {
    override fun plus(other: Vector3d): Vector3d = TODO()
    override fun minus(other: Vector3d): Vector3d = TODO()
    override fun times(other: Vector3d): Vector3d = TODO()
    override fun div(other: Vector3d): Vector3d = TODO()
}
```

This makes more overheard for working with primitive doubles as now you have to wrap and unwrap them but it does allow you to use generics for defining `Linear`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you technically can create a class using generics, but the class won't know how to multiplicate T with T, as it is a sub-class of [`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/), and `Any` doesn't support this operater. Through [smart-casts](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) you could evaluate, what kind of T is given:

```
class Linear<T>(val a: T, val b: T) {
    fun eval(c: T): Any {
        when {
            a is Double -> return a * c as Double + b as Double
            a is Double -> return a * c as Vector3d + b as Vector3d
            else -> return Unit
        }
}
```

See [generics](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) on Kotlin-docs for more information.

I wouldn't consider this good practice, as the method doesn't have a clear (and type-save) return type and is very inflexible, but at least it provides type-safety for your arguments.

Another alternative would be to use `Number` (or `Double`) as a super-class for `Vector3d` and implement the methods as length. This also wouldn't be that much of a good practice, but at least you could use `<Number>` as generics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a generic type with the upper bound. `Koltin` allows to define several upper bounds which looks like your use case:

```
fun <T> copyWhenGreater(list: List<T>, threshold: T): List<String>
    where T : CharSequence,
          T : Comparable<T> {
    return list.filter { it > threshold }.map { it.toString() }
}
```

Please see more in [the official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#upper-bounds).